# Dataframe convertirlo a Table

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo este dataframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
> datos$x <- as.factor(datos$x)
> class(datos)
[1] "data.frame"
> str(datos)
'data.frame':   55 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x    : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ grupo: Factor w/ 11 levels "CF","CM","CTO",..: 10 10 10 10 10 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ y    : int  7 5 7 8 7 6 5 8 6 9 ...
> barplot(datos)
Error in barplot.default(datos) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

Y me produce ese error

Ahora en el ejemplo que me dieron que se trabaja con el paquete vcd es:

```
> data("HairEyeColor", package = "datasets")
> class(HairEyeColor)
[1] "table"
> hec <- margin.table(HairEyeColor, 2:1) #transpuso 
> class(hec)
[1] "table"
> barplot(hec, beside = TRUE, legend = TRUE)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer un `barplot` agrupado, con R base, deberás modificar la forma del `dataframe`:

```
datos_new <- reshape(datos, idvar="grupo", timevar="x", direction="wide")
rownames(datos_new) <- datos_new$grupo
datos_new <- t(datos_new[, -1])

datos_new

    Prod Log CM DEE
y.1    7   6  4   6
y.2    5   5  6   7
y.3    7   8 10   7
y.4    8   6  5   7
y.5    7   9  9   7
```

Hemos cambiado la orientación a un formato ancho mediante `reshape` y convertido la columna `grupo` en una `rowname`. Ahora si podemos hacer:

```
barplot(datos_new,  beside=TRUE)
```

Resultado:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]